# reference value in php for scoring (min x = 1, max y = 100)

Tags: php, math, max, min, scoring

I'd like to do a tiny scoring, but I stumble at maths. I guess you will handle it :-) I have a few values: e.g. **124, 426, 100, 24, 41**. The highest shell be MaxScore = 100 (here 426), and the minimum MinScore = 1 (here 24). Every value (here 124,100,41) between *MaxScore* and *MinScore* shell get an own Score, related to min and max.

With php *max()*, I get

```
$max = max(124, 426, 100, 24, 41);
```

**426** as the highest and with *min()*

```
$min = min(124, 426, 100, 24, 41);
```

**24** as the lowest value. Fine.

Next step could be like: 426 = 100 and 24 = 1. But the rest? What's the calculation? As you can see, it's not a programmer problem (not yet), rather a maths-issue. I hope I did make myself clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this seems to work.  Might have put more parenthesis in than needed.

```
$new_val = 1 + (($val - $min) * (99 / ($max - $min)))
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Awesome, you made my day... or night. Thank you very much! Greetings from Berlin! Good night!

Comment: No problem, I love figuring out these little math formula thingys.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is apply each value to be `$val * ($max - $min) / 100;`

EDIT I had that backwards. It'll be `$val / (($max - $min) / 100);`  This takes the ratio of the difference between `$min` and `$max` divided into 100 pieces.  So each piece will then have the ratio applied to it.  This would make 100 be `100 / ((426 - 24) / 100) = 24.875`  and it would reduce all values to a number between 1 and 100.

EDIT. To get the min to be 1 and the max to be 100 and maintain relationships between scores we need to apply the ratio and subtract a contstant.

Verified Andrew Nee's comment seems to do the trick.

```
php -r "$a = array(123,426,100,24,41);print_r(array_map(function($val){$min=24;$max=426;return 1 + (($val - $min) * (99/($max - $min)));},$a));"

Array
(
    [0] => 25.380597014925
    [1] => 100
    [2] => 19.716417910448
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 5.1865671641791
)
```

Comment: If you want to take the full distribution into account rather than just the min/max then you'll need to do a bit more. Please indicate if that is more desireable.

Comment: But he wants the min (in this example 24) to be 1.  Your formula would make the min about 6ish, right?

Comment: Yeah, reducing 426 to 100 and 24 to 1 would require a different function.  And the ratio of each will be different. Not sure it'll accurately portray the original scores relative to each other if we do exactly what was asked.  I assumed they didn't know exactly what they wanted and just threw an idea out there to get all numbers in the range with an even ratio.  We need to add a constant to the formula. One that is so - `max(abs(0 - $max / (($max - $min) / 100)), abs(0 - $min / (($max - $min) / 100)))`

Comment: The max might not be necessary. let me check my math.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much, but I'm a bit confused. With the this calculation 24 (the min) is not 0 or 1, and 426 (the max) is not 100 (or is it my win-calc?). @AndrewNee Yes, but it's not that necessary, if it's too complicated, skip it.

Comment: Ok this seems to work... 1 + (($val - $min) * (99 / ($max - $min)))